# replace every letter/number in string thats not necessary

Tags: c#, regex, string, double

I'm trying to extract all possitive of negative numbers (doubles) from a string and I want a string in return.

example : CO2: 404 ppm CO2

The method I wrote :

```
public string extractNumber(string input)
    {

        var allowedChars = "01234567890.,-";
        return new string(input.Where(c => allowedChars.Contains(c)).ToArray());
    }
```

This gives me an output string :

```
24042
```

my question :

Is this the best method for doing this ? Or can I do it with regex.Replace ?

If I use this method . How can I delete the 2's in front and back ?
**EDIT:**

inputs : ( all seperate lines )

```
Humidity: 33 %  
Temperature: -25.7 deg C  
Visible light: 112 lx  
Infrared radiation: 1802.5 mW/m2  
UV index: 10.12  
CO2: 4004 ppm CO2  
Pressure: 102126 Pa
```

needed outputs :

```
33  
-25.7  
112  
1802.5  
10.12  
4004  
102126
```

Thank you

Comment: It is _a_ way to do this. Quite effective too. What are your constraints? When you say "best", what is the criteria? Readability? Lines of code? Speed of execution? Something else? You have also not stated what the rules for what needs to be kept and what not should be (i.e - why should the 2 at the end be removed?)

Comment: It just needs to be effective . I need to get the values from the string to use it in a GUI . What should be kept is a (negative) double only

Comment: Perhaps put some examples of good and bad inputs and their expected outputs (instead of what your method returns, as it isn't what you want)?

Comment: inputs : 

Humidity: 33 %
Temperature: -25.7 deg C
Visible light: 112 lx
Infrared radiation: 1802.5 mW/m2
UV index: 10.12
CO2: 4004 ppm CO2
Pressure: 102126 Pa

outputs : 

33
-25.7
112
1802.5
10.12
4004
102126

Comment: Probably better to *edit* these into your question...

Comment: So, any set of numbers which have whitespace before/after them (or otherwise are at the start/end of the line)?

Comment: Yes, only the number inbetween !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex to extract numbers (including decimals, and minus sign) which *have a space before and after*:

```
(?<=\s)-?[\d.]+(?=\s)
```

- `(?<=\s)` is a lookbehind that looks for a space `\s` before the number
- `-?` denotes a minus sign may or may not be present
- `[\d.]+` matches any digits and a decimal point
- `(?=\s)` is a positive lookahead that looks for a space `\s` after the number

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JbtE9C/1/)

You can use `Regex.Match()` to directly extract the numbers that you are looking for.

```
string input = "CO2: 4004 ppm CO2";
Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<=\s)-?[\d.]+(?=\s)");
var p = re.Match(input);
// Output: 4004
```

Here's a demo: [Dotnet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xmUb1c)

Comment: Should I use regex replace ?

Comment: You can simply do `Regex.Match()` to get the outputs back. I've added a simple cornet fiddle sample in the answer as an example. Hope it helps!

Comment: This regex matches `.......` https://regex101.com/r/JbtE9C/2  @AlessioMusone , or just don't care ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution using regular expressions:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\b-?\d+(\.?\d+)?\b");
Match matches = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matches.Success)
{
    // matched text: matches.Value
    // match start: matches.Index
    // match length: matches.Length
    matches = matches.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a core of how a language parses a numeric value (sans decoration).
Since you don't have any usable boundary's, you can use a fallback
whitespace boundary.

`(?<!\S)-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?!\S)`

Explained

```
 (?<! \S )                     # Whitespace boundary
 -?                            # Optional '-' sign
 (?:
      \d+                           # digit required
      (?: \. \d* )?                 # optional '.' and 0 to many digits
   |                              # or,
      \. \d+                        # required '.' and required digits
 )
 (?! \S )                      # Whitespace boundary
```